# Estimates on standard normal distribution $P(\vert X\vert\le x)\le x$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am studying a proof of Paley Wiener Zygmund and there arises the following problem.

> Let $X\sim N(0,1)$. Why does $P(\vert X\vert \le x)\le x$ holds true?

Could someone provide me a proof why this is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $x\in \mathbb R^+$, you have
\begin{align*}
\int_{-x}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right) dy&\leq \int_{-x}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{0^2}{2}\right) dy\\
&\leq\int_{-x}^x\frac{1}{2}\\
&=x
\end{align*}
The first line is due to the fact that $\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)$ attains it's maximum in $0$, the second line is because $\pi > 2$. As a side note, the second inequality is strict except when $x=0$.